# Lemon lisbon issue and Brown branches on orange tree

Tags: fruit-trees

I have a problem with lemon leaves. I have a 3,5 yrs old lemon tree in a container which has been dormant from october till now and i have moved it outside (15 degrees celsius). Almost all leaves fell down, with only 5 leaves left (winter leaf drop). Those leaves have bronze/brown color on the end of the leaf and new leaves are not growing, although now we have at least 8 hrs of sun.

Also, some leaves are becoming pale green and the whole tree is green, root is ok. I have been fertilizing it with citrus and magnesium fertilizers and I am not overwatering., but still no progresa.

Orange tree has dropped all of its leaves and shows no progress on new leaves. Also, end of branches have that bronze/brown color as lemon leaves.

Could you help me out? I have searched but i could not find a solution. The citruses have regular fertilization and watering plus the sun (although the soil around the root is not very warm). [image]